# how can we use $_POST variable in a class

Tags: php

I was just learning class in PHP and so I am messing around with it.  I just tried to get a value from a user and display it using a class.  However, when I tried to use `$_POST` variable inside the class it shows an error.

Here is the code:

```
<form action="classess.php" method="POST" >
<b>Enter the rate : </b>
<input type="text" name="price" />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Click" />
</form>
<?php

class rating
{
  public $rate = $_POST['price'];
  public function Display()
  {
    echo $this -> rate;
  }
}

$alex = new rating;
$alex ->Display();
?>
```

Comment: Be sure the variable is set before. http://php.net/manual/fr/function.isset.php

Comment: What error did it show?

Comment: @RocketHazmat: syntex error unexpected T_Variable where I used $_POST

Comment: @PeterFour : But where else to define a variable.It has to be inside class.

Comment: @Madara The variable is define when the form is posted. Uchiha is right, you have to assign in a constructor or in a setter

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You cannot have *statements* inside of property definitions. Use a constructor instead:

```
class Rating {
    public $rate;

    public function __construct($price) {
        $this->$rate = $price;
    }

    public function display() {
        echo $this->rate;
    }
}

$alex = new Rating($_POST['price']);
$alex->display();
```

### Some points:

- Don't make it hard on yourself. If you need something to make the class work, ask it in the constructor.
- `ClassNames` are usually written in CapitalCase, and `methodNames` are written in camelCase.
- It might be preferable for the `display()` function to actually `return` the rate, instead of `echo`ing it. You can do more stuff with a returned value.

Answer (score 2):

This is your correct HTML part

```
<form action="classess.php" method="POST" >
<b>Enter the rate : </b>
<input type="text" name="price" />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Click" />
</form>
```

This is your corrected PHP part

```
<?php
class Rating
{
  public $rate;
  public function __construct() {
    $this->$rate = $_POST['price'];
  }
  public function display()
  {
    echo $this -> rate;
  }
}

$alex = new rating;
$alex ->Display();
?>
```

Let me explain it..

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->rate = $_POST['price'];
  }
```

is setting up your variables i.e constructing the class..

```
public function display()
  {
    return $this->rate;
  }
```

This function inside classes actually getting the value of var $rate

```
$alex = new rating;
echo $alex->display();
```

then simply init the class and use the function.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to assign a value in the wrong place. You need to assign your value in the constructor.

Why not do it this way?

```
<form action="classess.php" method="POST" >
<b>Enter the rate : </b>
<input type="text" name="price" />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Click" />
</form>
<?php

class rating
{
  var $rate;

  function rating($price)
  {
    $this->rate = $price;
  }

  public function Display()
  {
    echo $this->rate;
  }
}

$alex = new rating($_POST['price']);
$alex->Display();
?>
```

This way you can initialize the value when you create the object. It gives you a little bit more flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    class rating
    {
      public $rate;
    }

    $alex = new rating;
    $alex->rate=$_POST['price'];
?>
```

Result can be obtained simply with this method.

Answer (score 0):

statement `public $rate = $_POST['price'];` can not be *initialized*

why? because variable initializations will happen in *compile time* when code is not interpreted yet and so **the compiler knows nothing from $_POST['price']** at the time that the initialization is going on

---

this is also pointed out in [php documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php):

> This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value.