# How to pass GET variable to class Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, oop

hello guys i want to send dr. id from one page to appointment page i know how to pass variable

```
<a href="<?php add_query_arg( 'c', $my_value_for_c, site_url( '/some_other_page/' ) )?>">

function add_custom_query_var( $vars ){
  $vars[] = "c";
  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_custom_query_var' );
```

and fetch this variable by  `$my_c = get_query_var( 'c' );`

BUT the problem is when i `print_r($_GET['c']);` it will print outside of class but goes bank inside how to retrieve inside of class..
--class code--

```
$my_c = get_query_var( 'c' );
print_r($my_c); // working fine

if (!class_exists('Appointments')) {

    class Appointments {

        var $version = "1.4.4-beta-1";
       // dont know how to retrieve $_GET['c'] inside class

        /**
         * Constructor
         */
        function Appointments() {
            $this->__construct();
                    $my_c = get_query_var( 'c' );
                    echo $my_c;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17549538/how-can-we-use-post-variable-in-a-class),

> You cannot have statements inside of property definitions. Use a constructor instead.

They recommend passing the variable inside the constructor.

```
class Appointments {
    public $c;
    public function __construct($query_var) {
        $this->$c = $query_var;
    }

    public function doSomethingWithC() {
        return $this->c;
    }
}

$my_c = get_query_var( 'c' );
$appointment = new Appointments($my_c);
echo $appointment->doSomethingWithC(); // echos the value of c
```

Comment: actually i want that $my_c value inside class function... for eg public function myvar(){//here i want that $my_c value }

Comment: @SunilKashyap I am not sure if I am following correctly, but I have modified my answer.

Answer (score 1):

use `$my_c = get_query_var( 'c' );` function to get query parameters.